# Generic method call cannot convert from class name to full class name

Tags: c#, generics

I have an interface as follows:

```
 public interface ISelectEntity
{
    List<T> GetFromDB<T, O>(O data);
}
```

I'm implementing it as follows within a StatusCodes class

```
List<StatusCodes> ISelectEntity.GetFromDB<StatusCodes, StatusCodesInputParameters>(StatusCodesInputParameters data)
    {
        return EntitiesClass.PopulateStatusCodes(EntitiesDAL.GetStatusCodes(data));
    }
```

I'm receiving the following error, however:

> Error 2   Argument '1': cannot convert from 'StatusCodesInputParameters' to 'Namespace.StatusCodesInputParameters'

Assuming that my namespace is called Namespace, that's the error I receive. All of this is within this one namespace.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change method signatures in derived classes. You could define the generic argument on the interface though instead of doing it on the method:

```
public interface ISelectEntity<T, O>
{
    List<T> GetFromDB(O data);
}
```

and a sample explicit implementation might look like this:

```
public class Foo : ISelectEntity<StatusCodes, StatusCodesInputParameters>
{
    List<StatusCodes> ISelectEntity<StatusCodes, StatusCodesInputParameters>.GetFromDB(StatusCodesInputParameters data)
    {
        return EntitiesClass.PopulateStatusCodes(EntitiesDAL.GetStatusCodes(data));
    }
}
```

and a sample implicit implementation:

```
public class Foo : ISelectEntity<StatusCodes, StatusCodesInputParameters>
{
    public List<StatusCodes> GetFromDB(StatusCodesInputParameters data)
    {
        return EntitiesClass.PopulateStatusCodes(EntitiesDAL.GetStatusCodes(data));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  I didn't realize.